# How do I iterate dictionary with lists as values in Django template?

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary with lists as values (truncated to give you an example):

imageFiles:

```
for prop in context['results'][0]:
        imageFolderPath ='./media/uploaded/prop_images/' + prop.property_ID
        if os.path.isdir(imageFolderPath):
            imageFileList[prop.property_ID] = [f for f in listdir(imageFolderPath) if isfile(join(imageFolderPath, f))]
    

context['imageFiles'] = [imageFileList]
```

Here is what shows up when I print it directly in the template:

```
[{'R01': ['02secparking27.jpg', '10-2017-ff-detail-1200x627.jpg', '1200x820.jpg', '12539233_web1_180704-VMS-parking-lot.jpg', '16.12.01-519196006.jpg',], 
'R02': ['asdasd.jpg','12131asad.jpg','asdasdasd.jpg']}]
```

In the template, I am trying to access the image names by iterating but I am getting no values.

```
{% for keys,values in imageFiles %}
   {% for x in values %}
     <p>  {{X}}  </p>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

getting error

> "Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 9."

I also tried imageFiles.items as suggested in other posts and it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?  Wracking my brain here.

Comment: It would help if you showed the code that passes in the `imageFiles` argument to the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're passing in:

```
context['imageFiles'] = [imageFileList]
```

Which is pretty confusing, for no good reason. What you're calling `imageFileList` isn't a list, but a dictionary. Then, what you pass into the template is a list with a single element, namely that dictionary.

Fix: Pass in the dictionary (it would be even nicer if you changed the name of `imageFileList` to something less confusing):

```
context['imageFiles'] = imageFileList
```

In your template:

```
{% for key, value in imageFiles.items %} 
    {% for x in values %}
        <p>  {{x}}  </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed

```
dct = your input dictionary
```

code:

```
[value for keys, values in dct.items() for value in values]
```

will give you the below list of file names:

```
['02secparking27.jpg',
 '10-2017-ff-detail-1200x627.jpg',
 '1200x820.jpg',
 '12539233_web1_180704-VMS-parking-lot.jpg',
 '16.12.01-519196006.jpg',
 'asdasd.jpg',
 '12131asad.jpg',
 'asdasdasd.jpg']
```